# WPF How can i do it with 1 event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem, i have 5 buttons that load txt files from system and show it as string on textblocks but i dont know how to do it without 5 event handlers

```
    private void OnClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {            
                OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                numbers1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
            }
```

OnClick1 is button1, numbers1 is a textblock1
now i have 5 codes like this (with numbers2.Text, numbers3.Text etc) how can i do it shorter

Comment: The `sender` parameter will tell you what button was clicked

Comment: i know what button is clicked, i want to connect buttons to textblocks or something so i can use only one OnClick1 istead of five

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding what you are asking. However, if you want the different buttons to use the same click event. Then the click event is going to have to be able to distinguish “which” button was clicked in order to know which text box to use.

In this case, I recommend you give each button a name and then in the click event, cast the sender as a `Button`, then check its name to determine which text box to use. All buttons are wired up to this ONE (1) event. Example something like…

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  Button btnSender = (Button)sender;
  TextBox tb = null;
  switch (btnSender.Name) {
    case "btn1":
      tb = txt1;
      break;
    case "btn2":
      tb = txt2;
      break;
    case "btn3":
      tb = txt3;
      break;
    case "btn4":
      tb = txt4;
      break;
  }
  if (tb != null) {
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
      tb.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, you knew exatcly what i was talking about, thanks so much

Comment: Did you notice that he used the `sender` parameter to tell what button was pressed?  The pattern (if you want to have one handler handle many controls) is to use the `sender` parameter to determine what to do.  Just like in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started I think

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
            List<TextBlock> textBlocks = new List<TextBlock>();
            textBlocks.Add(txt1);
            textBlocks.Add(txt2);
            textBlocks.Add(txt3);
            textBlocks.Add(txt4);
            textBlocks.Add(txt5);

            int count = 0;
          
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                
                foreach (String files in openFileDialog.FileNames)
                {
                    var currentText = textBlocks[count];
                    currentText.Text = File.ReadAllText(files);
                    count++;
                }
                
               
            }
        }
```

Here is the xaml code

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
            <Button Name="btnLoad" Content="Load All" Click="btnLoad_Click" ></Button>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txt2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txt3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txt4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txt5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: thanks for help, you are rly close, but i need 5 different buttons and every button loads string to different textblock like you did but i need 5 different buttons so badly